# First Character of String Lowercase - C#

Tags: c#, string, lowercase

How can I make the first character of a string lowercase?

For example: `ConfigService`

And I need it to be like this: `configService`

Comment: Did you check this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565015/bestpractice-transform-first-character-of-a-string-into-lower-case

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135317/make-first-letter-of-a-string-upper-case Instead `ToUpper` change it to `ToLower`.

Comment: Note: anything "first character" related will be very dangerous when talking about anything outside simple unicode. Combining diacritics, conjugate pairs, and right-to-left will all cause it problems

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This will work:

```
public static string? FirstCharToLowerCase(this string? str)
{
    if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && char.IsUpper(str[0]))
        return str.Length == 1 ? char.ToLower(str[0]).ToString() : char.ToLower(str[0]) + str[1..];

    return str;
}
```

(This code arranged as "C# Extension method")

Usage:

```
myString = myString.FirstCharToLowerCase();
```

Comment: Don't forget to check for empty strings.

Comment: And strings that only contains one character.

Comment: Note: `char.IsLower(str[0])` check is not required, but may speed up an execution.

Comment: why the [CanBeNull] is not supported in ASp net core.

Comment: [CanBeNull] used to be supported but the new convention is to add a ? after the string. I made an edit to this question cause of this.

Comment: The method can be made way simpeler anno 2022: `return string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? str : char.ToLower(str[0]) + str[1..];`

Answer (score 23):

One way:

```
string newString = oldString;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(newString))
    newString = Char.ToLower(newString[0]) + newString.Substring(1);
```

For what it's worth, an extension method:

```
public static string ToLowerFirstChar(this string input)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        return input;

    return char.ToLower(input[0]) + input.Substring(1);
}
```

Usage:

```
string newString = "ConfigService".ToLowerFirstChar(); // configService
```

Comment: Does this work well with DBCS?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar .NET has Unicode strings. And char represents UTF-16 character

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Correct. The same question applies to surrogate pairs, though, which would not be handled correctly (and just don't get handled correctly in general, in most code I've seen).

Comment: @AmitJoki In that case, `Char.ToLower` returns the original character, so the string remains unchanged.

Comment: @AmitJoki That is because you are printing out `s` and not `newString`

Comment: @AmitJoki: the check is redundant. However, i have shown an extension which makes it clearer. Was that the reason for the downvote or have i missed something else?

Comment: Sorry @TimSchmelter It was my mistake

Comment: I don't know the reason, why my answer was marked as answer :) Thought this post will be marked as answer

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I see. I didn't actually know that :-)

Answer (score 8):

You could try this:

```
lower = source.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + source.Substring(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    string FirstLower(string s)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return s;
        return s[0].ToString().ToLower() + s.Substring(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this function:

```
public string GetStringWithFirstCharLowerCase(string value)
{
    if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value")
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) return value;

    char firstChar = Char.ToLowerInvariant(value[0]);

    if (value.Length == 1) return firstChar;

    return firstChar + value.Substring(1);
}
```

Please note that further overloading will be necessary if support for other languages is required.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static string Upper_To_Lower(string text)
    {
        if (Char.IsUpper(text[0]) == true) { text = text.Replace(text[0], char.ToLower(text[0])); return text; }

        return text;
    }

    public static string Lower_To_Upper(string text)
    {
        if (Char.IsLower(text[0]) == true) { text = text.Replace(text[0], char.ToUpper(text[0])); return text; }

        return text;
    }
```

Hope this will help you ! here i made two methods taking as parameter any string and return the string with the first letter uppercase or lowercase according to the method you will use

Answer (score 1):

```
string test = "ConfigService";
string result = test.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + test.Substring(1);
```

Comment: Also, using `Substring` method just for getting first char seems a little bit over the top :)

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do this:

```
Char.ToLowerInvariant(yourstring[0]) + yourstring.Substring(1)
```

Simple and gets the job done.

EDIT:

Looks like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565015/bestpractice-transform-first-character-of-a-string-into-lower-case) had the same idea. :)

Answer (score 1):

This can help you,changes first character to lower if it is upper and also checks for null or empty and only whitespace string:

```
string str = "ConfigService";
string strResult = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) && char.IsUpper(str, 0) ? str.Replace(str[0],char.ToLower(str[0])) : str;
```