# EnumMemberAttribute Value is ignored by DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, enums, datacontract, datacontractjsonserializer

This is my code:

```
[DataContract] // (Name = "Type")]
 public enum Purpose
 {
   [EnumMember(Value = "definitionTarget")]
   DefinitionTarget = 0,
   [EnumMember(Value = "definitionSource")]
   DefinitionSource = 1,
   [EnumMember(Value = "semanticRole")]
   SemanticRole = 2,
   [EnumMember(Value = "dataType")]
   DataType = 3
}
```

I want the enum values to display according to the strings given, not the integer values. For some reason, the values are ignored.

The serialization code is nothing fancy:

```
protected string GetRuntimeValue(RuntimeValue value)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    _serializer.WriteObject(ms, value);
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
}
```

I went to [the Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and found an example with some boilerplate code where they inherit IExtensibleDataObject (no explanation why). I added the code to my base class, no change.

What am I doing wrong? Should be something simple, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad news is that `DataContractJsonSerializer` ignores the `EnumMember` attribute and this is [by design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/stand-alone-json-serialization#enumerations-and-json):

> Enumeration member values are treated as numbers in JSON, which is
> different from how they are treated in data contracts, where they are
> included as member names. ... The EnumMemberAttribute and the NonSerializedAttribute attributes are ignored if used.

A Microsoft support agent also [confirmed this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a1b8f0e1-82d9-4d7b-bf97-b1d0620fca71/datacontractjsonserializer-serialization-of-enummember?forum=wcf) and suggested a kludge which is to expose a property decorated with `DataMember` for the serializer to use instead, which calls `Enum.GetName()` to get the string name of the enum value.

It would need to be modified in your case to return a string with the first letter converted to lower case:

```
[DataContract]
public class RuntimeValue
{
    public Purpose Purpose { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Purpose")]
    string PurposeString
    {
        get { return Enum.GetName(typeof(Purpose), this.Purpose).FirstCharacterToLower(); }
        set { this.Purpose = (Purpose)Enum.Parse(typeof(Purpose), value, true); }
    }
}
```

Uses an extension method borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3565148/397817) to do the lower case stuff:

```
public static string FirstCharacterToLower(this string str)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) || Char.IsLower(str, 0))
        return str;

    return Char.ToLowerInvariant(str[0]) + str.Substring(1);
}
```

Testing:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetRuntimeValue(new RuntimeValue()));
```

Output:

> {"Purpose":"definitionTarget"}

---

Personally I would use JSON.NET instead if possible but for the sake of my answer I am assuming that you have already considered that option and have good reason to stick with this serializer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, I considered JSON.net but the data contract mechanism offers too many advantages (especially when it comes to multiple uses in web services), so I can't avoid it. 

It's amazing that they ignored their own attribute though.